# Batch process wav files with sox within subfolders

Tags: batch-file, sox

I have a batch script file that converts existing `wav` files to Mono wav files to a created folder called "Mono"

**CODE**

```
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

2>nul mkdir "Mono"
set "_sox=C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe"

for %%i in ("*.wav") do "%_sox%" -S "%%~fi" "Mono\%%~ni.wav" channels 1
```

I have to place this `.bat` file in the folder that I want converted.  My folder structure is expanding and I have to go through each folder manually, place the `.bat` file and run the script to get the resultant mono files.

Here is an example of my folder structure:

```
Main Folder
    |
    |______fold1
    |        |_____file1.wav
    |        |_____file2.wav
    |
    |______fold2
    |        |_____file1.wav
    |        |_____file2.wav
    |
    |______fold3
             |_____file1.wav
             |_____file2.wav
```

With the expanding folder structure, I wanted to place the `.bat` file in the Main Folder, run the script, and the script will go through each subfolder, create the "Mono" folder in each subfolder and place the converted mono wav files in there.  This should be the updated file structure with the converted mono files:

```
Main Folder
    |
    |______fold1
    |        |_____file1.wav
    |        |_____file2.wav
    |        |_____Mono
    |                |______file1.wav
    |                |______file2.wav
    |______fold2
    |        |_____file1.wav
    |        |_____file2.wav
    |        |_____Mono
    |                |______file1.wav
    |                |______file2.wav
    |______fold3
    |        |_____file1.wav
    |        |_____file2.wav
    |        |_____Mono
    |                |______file1.wav
    |                |______file2.wav
```

Please let me know how to modify the `.bat` file to accomplish this task.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "_sox=C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe"

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN (`DIR /B "%~dp0"`) DO (
    MKDIR "%~dp0\%%A\Mono" 2> NUL
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%B IN (`DIR /B "%~dp0\%%A\*.wav"`) DO (
        "%_sox%" -S "%~dp0\%%A\%%B" "%~dp0\%%A\Mono\%%~nB.wav" channels 1
    )
)
```

`DIR /B` lists every file and folder within the specified folder.

For each folder it finds, it will create a Mono folder within it, and then run the sox command for each `.wav` file found.

Hope this helps. Love your name btw

Comment: @Joe...right back at you!  I do see the Mono Folder getting created correctly, however, the program is failing as there seems to an error in the `open` file.  The subfolder is missing when the open command is initiated by `sox`.

Comment: For example,this is the error I get: `C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe FAIL formats: can't open input file C:\Users\JoeBoo\OneDrive\Desktop\ForSVMEmail\NoAudios - Copy\101415-3-0-2.wav: No such file or directory`...the path should actually be `C:\Users\JoeBoo\OneDrive\Desktop\ForSVMEmail\NoAudios - Copy\fold1\101415-3-0-2.wav`

Comment: @Joe Blunder on my part. I changed ```%%~fB``` to ```%~dp0\%%A\%%B```, it should work now. ```DIR /B``` Only gives the file names, so there's no full path available.